# Bash if $? ignored

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I'm making a postinstall script, but for some reason my menu doesnt work with if comands.

Its supposed to echo whatever editor i selected (Well, for now), but only echos emacs. Help?

(Code below)

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(whoami) != root ]
then
    echo "Sorry, this script must be run as root. Try sudo su, and then running it!"
    exit 1
fi

which dialog > /dev/null

if [ $? = 1 ]
then
    echo "Sorry, you need to install dialog first."
    exit 1
fi

choice=$(dialog --no-cancel --backtitle "Jacks Post Install Script" --title "Welcome" --menu "" 20 40 35 1 "Install crap already!" 2 "Enable ssh" 3 "Reboot" 4 "Exit" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-)

function insstp1 {
    dialog --cancel-label "No thanks" --extra-button --extra-label "Vim" --ok-label "Emacs" --backtitle "Jacks Post Install Script" --title "Pick an editor!" --yesno "I bet you will pick emacs. Seriusly." 5 40
    echo $? #emacs 0 vim 3 no 1
    if [ $? == 0 ]
    then
    echo "Emacs"
    fi

    if [ $? == 3 ]
    then
        echo "Vim"
    fi

    if [ $? == 1 ]
    then
    echo "nope"
    fi
}

case $choice in
    1) insstp1 ;;
    2) enablssh ;;
    3) reboot ;;
    4) clear; exit 0 ;;
esac
```

Comment: `echo $?` will work, but will then set `$?` to the exit code of the `echo` command. Suggestion: immediately after `dialog`, store the value of `$?` into another variable.

Comment: Note that you can test the exit status of a command by simply `if commad; then ...;fi`.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong syntax `==` should be `-eq` and **of course** avoid the *echoes*.

```
dialog --cancel-label "No thanks" --extra-button --extra-label "Vim" --ok-label "Emacs" --backtitle "Jacks Post Install Script" --title "Pick an editor!" --yesno "I bet you will pick emacs. Seriusly." 5 40
choice2=$?
        
if [ $choice2 -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "Emacs"
fi
```

From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions):

> `arg1 OP arg2`
>
> OP is one of ‘-eq’, ‘-ne’, ‘-lt’, ‘-le’, ‘-gt’, or ‘-ge’.
> These arithmetic binary operators return true if arg1 is equal to, not
> equal to, less than, less than or equal to, greater than, or greater
> than or equal to arg2, respectively. Arg1 and arg2 may be positive or
> negative integers.

Comment: True, but `[ $? == 0 ]` will have the same exit status as `[ $? -eq 0 ]` in `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Store `$?` und use a case construction. You are trying to store the result of your first dialog in a variable choice, but it will contain the stdout. This choice should be done with `$?` as well:

```
    function insstp1 {
        dialog --cancel-label "No thanks" --extra-button --extra-label "Vim" --ok-label "Emacs" --backtitle "Jacks Post Install Script" --title "Pick an editor!" --yesno "I bet you will pick emacs. Seriusly." 5 40
        editchoice=$? #emacs 0 vim 3 no 1
        case ${editchoice} in
           0) echo "Emacs" ;;
           3) echo "Vim" ;;
           1) echo "nope";;
           *) echo "Let me pick for you ...";;
        fi
    }

dialog --no-cancel --backtitle "Jacks Post Install Script" --title "Welcome" --menu "" 20 40 35 1 "Install crap already!" 2 "Enable ssh" 3 "Reboot" 4 "Exit" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-
choice=$?

case ${choice} in
    1) insstp1 ;;
    2) enablssh ;;
    3) reboot ;;
    4) clear; exit 0 ;;
esac
```